# Let $a_n$ be a sequence s.t $a_1 > 0 \land a_{n+1} = a_n + \dfrac{1}{a_n}$. Prove that $a_n$ is increasing and tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be a sequence s.t $a_1 > 0 \land a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{1}{a_n}$. Prove that $a_n$ is increasing and tends to infinity.

Proof:

Consider $a_{n+1} - a_n$:

$a_{n+1} - a_n = a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} - a_n = \frac{1}{a_n}$ This is greater than $0$. Thus, $a_n$ is increasing.

Now this is where I need some help. I would like to say that $a_n$ is unbounded and then conclude that monotone and unbounded implies tending to infinity.

Maybe by contradiction?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I agree. But an interesting "meta question" is this: Should older questions be closed as duplicates of a more recent questions? Perhaps it depends on the quality of the answers.

Comment: @PaulFrost This meta question already exist in fact : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16417/original-post-marked-as-duplicate (But I admit that this case is far from clear-cut.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You proved that $a_n$ is increasing. Assume that it is bounded. Then it would follow that $a_n$ is convergent to a real number $L>0$. But taking $n \to \infty$ into the recurrence relation gives 
$$ L+\frac{1}{L}=L$$ 
which is a contradiction. Therefore $a_n$ is unbounded and it follows that $a_n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, contradiction will work.  Assume the sequence is bounded by $M$.  Then $a_{n+1}=a_n+1/a_n> a_n+1/M$.  By induction, we have that $a_{n+k}>a_N+k/M$.  Thererefore $a_{n+M^2}>a_n+M^2/M=a_n+M>M$, which is a contradiction.